# Original IP not passed to container on single container Docker image on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ip-address

I have a Node.js server inside a Docker container on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have noticed that if I try to access the user's IP address via the request headers, I don't get the user's actual remote IP address. Instead I get what seems to be the IP address of the Docker container - `172.19.0.1`.

I'm sure there is something simple about how Docker or Elastic Beanstalk is configured that I need to change to get the desired behaviour - but I don't know what needs to change.

Something in my Dockerfile?
A flag or something in my `docker build` command before I push & deploy my container?
Some configuration on AWS in the ELB or Elastic Beanstalk?

Would really appreciate some pointers on where to start!

Comment: Which request header have you searched for the client IP ? `X-Forwarded-For` ?

Comment: May that help you (but I've not tried yet): with Elastic Beanstalk, you can configure a load balancer and tell him not to rewrite X-Forwarded-For fields: excerpt from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html: `You can change the listener protocol from HTTP to TCP if you want the load balancer to forward requests as-is. This prevents the load balancer from rewriting headers (including X-Forwarded-For) and does not work with sticky sessions`

Comment: I'm using Hapi so I'm trying to access `request.info.remoteAddress`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Hapi for Node.js, request headers are not available with `request.info` but with `request.headers`. Using `request.info` returns network level informations. You should use something like `request.headers[ 'X-Forwarded-For' ]` to get request level informations. Try displaying `request.headers` key-value pairs to discover the key that is linked to a value containing the IP address you want to find.

Comment: This works, kind of. `headers['x-forwarded-for']` gives me a string which is a comma-separated list of ip addresses, one of which is the right one. Is there no way to get Docker to pass down that IP address into the container under `request.info.remoteAddress`?

Comment: No, when using Docker with AWS EBS (Elastic Beanstalk). The Docker daemon can use different ways to expose ports, depending on its version and configuration. It can use iptables rules to expose container ports, or a subprocess, for each container, that act as a TCP proxy. The version of Docker used by AWS EBS and the way it configures Docker to expose ports changes the information available in `request.info.remoteAddress`, and you can not change the AWS EBS behaviour.

Comment: Cool, thanks. FYI anyone else with this problem - I think it's nginx or some other part of Elastic Beanstalk that's responsible for this, not Docker.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been touched on by Alexandre Fenyo, but if you are behind a load balancer this is probably what's being passed to your app as the client IP.

You can configure your nginx to set `real_ip_header: X-Forwarded For` and `real_ip_recursive: on`. This means nginx will scan the list of IPs you're receiving and set the client's as the first untrusted IP. You also need to pass a list of trusted IPs, which should be the CIDR block for your load balancer.

There's more detailed descriptions and answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/314574/nginx-real-ip-header-and-x-forwarded-for-seems-wrong#answer-414166)